# How do I apply a global filter on view tabs?

Tags: 7, views

In Drupal 7, I have a view where I show different view tabs of different content types. I want to apply a global filter on those view tabs.

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Global filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/global_filter) which creates filter widgets as blocks based on field or view of your choice and you can use the filter choices in ANY view as contextual filter.

Here is a simple example usage

- For `basic page` create `List (text) - field_choices` with widget `Select list` and values `choice1 choice2 choice3`

  > [image]
- Create some basic pages to include 1 of the 3 choices
- Create or modify the view and make it display the choice for each result

  > [image]
- Add contextual filter with choices as field and provide default value Global filter field

  > [image]
- Go to `Structure > blocks` and add `Global filter block 1` to a region of you choice and configure it to display `choice` field as a filter with default widget

  > [image]
- Visit the view page that has the contextual filter (on choices) and you should be able to filter the view based on the Global filter (choices dropdown widget)

  > [image]
- You can add the same contextual filter to as many views (or view displays) as you like

Comment: I have installed Views Global Filter module. Can you please guide me on how to use it?

Comment: The readme file of views global filter module is not working.

Comment: Its a complicated module to setup ... the readme is good but needs some playing around to get it done, I am updating with a simple example.

Comment: Thanks for the brief explanation. Just wanted to ask that, how will it work on other content types?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question.